# Error in using RGP User Interface (rgpui)

Tags: r

I'm using R version 3.3.1.
The RGP User Interface (rgpui) implements a modern web-based user interface to the Genetic Programming system RGP. I've install packages "rgp" and "rgpui" and type `symbolicRegressionUi() to start the web-based symbolic regression UI then navigate to http://localhost:1447. However, the web-based symbolic regression UI is unable to use because:
Warning: Error in server: could not find function "mcparallel"
Stack trace (innermost first):
    41: server
     2: runApp
     1: symbolicRegressionUi
Error in server (...) : could not find function "mcparallel"

There is no package (mcparallel) in R version 3.3.1. Is there any solution to use this web-based symbolic regression Ui? Please guide me, thank you very much.

Comment: `mcparallel` is a function of the `parallel` package

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Assuming you are using windows, attempting to install parallel package will give you a message that parallel uses 'fork' and only works on Unix like OS's.